# pandoc API producing html and pdf - images not found

Tags: pandoc

I produce HTML files to show in a browser and PDF from the same markdown source files with Pandoc using the API in Haskell code. I see a discrepancy in the way references to images are interpreted:

To test to include 3 images in markdown with the text

```
The 1st image ![example absolute reference - error in PDF, shown in HTML](/Blog/resources/1IMG.JPG)  is referenced absolutely with `/Blog/resources/1IMG.JPG`, and produces for `makePDF` an error  but the same ref is shown in HTML (understood as absolute reference relative to web root )  

test 2nd imgage ![2IMG ](Blog/resources/2IMG.JPG): `Blog/resources/2IMG.JPG` is incorrect relative reference and therefore not shown in HTML, but shown in PDF - interpreted relative to cwd . 

test 3rd image ![relative 3IMG]( resources/3IMG.JPG):   `resources/3IMG.JPG` is  relative reference to position of .md file. shown in HTML but not in PDF .
```

There seem to exist a difference between the interpretation of image inclusion in markdown code depending whether the output is going to HTML or PDF. I found numerous comments on this - mostly in conjunction with the `resource-path` command; I do not see a corresponding extension to include in the writer options.

What is the best way to resolve this problem? I have tried to use `\graphicspath{{...}}` included in the latex input, which seem a hack; best would probably an exension like `resource-root` where absolute path would start searching.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but I'd recommend to make the second method work (path relative to cwd).

The *mediabag* can be used to ensure a unified handling of images. Checkout [`fillMediaBag`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-3.1.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#v:fillMediaBag) and [`extractMedia`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-3.1.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class-IO.html#v:extractMedia). Those functions make it straight-forward to place the output in the right place relative to the HTML file.